# Links not properly aligning in nav bar

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a class project where we need to create a website from a psd file. I'm at the nav bar so far, but I'm having problems because the last 2 links in the nav bar are going below the first 2 elements, instead of being displayed in a line. The whole top part going from the logo to the last of the links is wrapped in a container with a 940px width. The letters in the links must be in 20px. This is how the website is supposed to look [Pic from the finished site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bIrf.png)

And this is how it's looking for me so far
[Test pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTF2U.png)

Here's my HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>NeoDance Studio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="Top">
            <div class="wrapperHeader">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="NeoDance Logo" width="356" height="48" class="logo">

            <nav class="NavBar">
                <ul class="links">
                    <li class="links"><a href="" class="links">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="links"><a href="" class="links">About</a></li>
                    <li class="links"><a href="" class="links">Class schedules</a></li>
                    <li class="links"><a href="" class="links">Performances</a></li>
                    <li class="links"><a href="" class="links">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="links"><a href="" class="links">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="ClearFix"></div>
            </div>    

        </header>
```

and my css

```
header.Top{
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #303030;
    overflow: hidden;
}    

div.wrapperHeader{
    width: 940px;
}



}

div.wrapper{
    width: 940px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img.logo{


    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #303030;



}

nav.NavBar{
    float: right;
    width: 480px;
    background-color: #303030;
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px

}

ul.links {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;



}

li.links{
    display: inline;
}

a.links{

    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    color: #8c8c8c;
    margin-right: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;


}

a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

I also have a general question about something that's been confusing me about Nav Bars. Which elements should I style to set each property? As you can see for example I have the font family and font size specified on the Anchor elements, while I have the container size on the Nav element and the display: inline in the list element. This is very confusing for me and I'm certainly sure it will be the source of some error. My professor insists on me using All those elements for a nav bar btw (The nav, with an UL nested inside, with anchors nested inside the lists)

Answer (score 1):

So I removed width from `nav.NavBar` and `div.wrapperHeader` so that there wouldn't be an issue when putting `nav.NavBar` on the same row as the logo by inserting `.wrapperHeader > * { display: inline-block; }`. This insertion code basically applies `display: inline-block` to all `.wrapperHeader`'s child elements.

I've cleaned up your css code a little bit, please see below:

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/julysfx/pen/rwXrYo?editors=1100#0)

Comment: Thank you for the fix, alas while it did help with the nav bar issue, it's now causing the logo to get out of alignment. Also the site must have the 940px wrapper